# Wait before execute next code in loop wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have a list of download links I am using cefsharp to download. I can't use webclient in order to download the files, the user must be logged in.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var lnk in collection) {
    Console.WriteLine(lnk);
    await TestAsync(lnk);
}

private  Task TestAsync(string lnk) {
    return Task.Run(() => TaskToDo(lnk));
}

private async void TaskToDo(string lnk) {
    await wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync(String.Format("window.location.href = '{0}'", lnk));
}
```

In my loop, I have a `Console.WriteLine` to print the links. In my program output, it prints all the links, then it downloads a file. The problem is that it only downloads the last file. I need it to wait and download the next file.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't block, just start downloading the next item when the previous finished, use a simple counter to track which list item your upto

Comment: that's the last solution i have in mind sir if i can't make this work

Comment: You have a `foreach` loop that selects an `item`, but within the loop `lnk` appears from the ether. What is the relationship between `item` and `lnk`? (kat1330 want to know, too.)

Comment: I don't believe what your trying is going to work

Comment: @HABO is updated the code for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
async void
```

That will NOT block by the caller, which is why your doing a Task.Run when you don't need to.

```
  foreach (var item in collection)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(lnk);
   await TestAsync(lnk);
  }

  private  Task TestAsync(string lnk)
  {
     return TaskToDo(lnk);
  }

  private Task TaskToDo(string lnk)
  {
     return wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync(String.Format("window.location.href = '{0}'", lnk));
  }
```

Comment: its still the same sir. it doesn't block the code from executing

Comment: await TestAsync(lnk); is what is supposed to do the download, right?

Comment: yes sir, the code await TestAsync(lnk); should download the file

Answer (score 0):

You are not using await keyword properly. In this case, you are telling that you want to wait each time you iterate loop. It is better to return `Task` from  `TestAsync(lnk)` and put on the task list.

So, instead `await` method in `foreach` loop you should use `Task.WhenAll()` for all tasks like in following example:

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (var lnk in collection)
{
     Console.WriteLine(lnk);
     var task = TestAsync(lnk);
     taskList.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

Regarding:

> The problem is that it only downloads the last file. I need it to wait
>   and download the next file.
>       How can I solve this?

I suspect that you cannot download file with `window.lotion.href` asynchronously because you are changing the location of window sequentially and before the previous operation complete!

Basically, while you are in middle of downloading LINK1 another task, example LINK3 will start to download and LINK1 will be stopped. This is the reason why you have only one file downloaded. Try to use `window.open()` or different some different technique.

Comment: i tried your code but still it doesn't download the other file. What do you mean by updating lnk? on my Console.WriteLine(lnk); the links are different from each other and the links are correct

Comment: I didn't see logic which change `lnk`. Never mind. Did you proof that your logic works with a synchronous code? Are you abele to download like that?

Comment: is this what you meant? in my loop i use the item variable. and in my console i use lnk? sorry about that. i removed the code for converting the value of item to link. i updated the code, thank you

Comment: Probably `window.location.href` is always overwritten with every task which is completed first. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be async all the way and you should not block on async code. Please refer to the @Stephen Cleary's MSDN article for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

The issue here is that your `TestAsync` method starts a new `Task`, which will be executed on a background thread, and returns immediately before the task has actually finisihed.

You should make the `TestAsync` method `async` and change the return type of the `TaskToDo` method to `Task` to be able to await this one:

```
foreach (var lnk in collection) {
    Console.WriteLine(lnk);
    await TestAsync(lnk);
}

private async Task TestAsync(string lnk)
{
    await TaskToDo(lnk);
}

private async Task TaskToDo(string lnk)
{
    await wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync(String.Format("window.location.href = '{0}'", lnk));
}
```